# mysql query where IN statement

Tags: mysql, sequence, database, between

I want to do the following:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM table WHERE value BETWEEN 3 AND 40;
```

But it should do the following:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM table WHERE value IN(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, ..., 40);
```

It should even print out zero count(id) for value between 3 and 40, but not value = x. I want to check if a value is in a sequence (1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 50).

Does anyone know how to achieve this with mysql?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a lot of confusion in this question.

Comment: You're asking atleast 3 different questions here, what do you actually want to do ?

Comment: I want to get a result set where COUNT(id) for values from 3 to 40, even those where COUNT(id) for value=x is zero.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have recursive functionality, so you're left with using the NUMBERS table trick -

1. Create a table that only holds incrementing numbers - easy to do using an auto_increment:

   ```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `example`.`numbers`;
   CREATE TABLE  `example`.`numbers` (
     `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
   ```
2. Populate the table using:

   ```
   INSERT INTO NUMBERS
     (id)
   VALUES
     (NULL)
   ```

   ...for as many values as you need.
3. This will return a list of the values you want to see counts for:

   ```
   SELECT n.id
     FROM NUMBERS n
    WHERE n.id BETWEEN 3 AND (? - 1)
       OR n.id BETWEEN (? + 1) AND 40
   ```
4. LEFT JOIN onto your existing table to be able to see where the COUNT is zero:

   ```
     SELECT x.id AS value,
            COALESCE(COUNT(y.id), 0) AS cnt
       FROM (SELECT n.id
               FROM NUMBERS n
              WHERE n.id BETWEEN 3 AND (? - 1)
                 OR n.id BETWEEN (? + 1) AND 40) x
   LEFT JOIN YOUR_TABLE yt ON yt.value = x.id
    GROUP BY x.id
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood your question:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM table WHERE value >= 3 AND value <= 40 AND value != 'x'
```

Edit: I think I know what you mean

```
SELECT COALESCE(count(id),0)  FROM table WHERE value BETWEEN 3 AND 40;
```

Comment: no! WHERE value = 3 OR value = 4 OR value = 5 OR ... Thank you, anyway.

Comment: @Vincent: That's logically equivalent, but `OR` can be notoriously bad for performance...

Comment: I want to COUNT(id) if there is no value e.g. 35, so I can't use WHERE value BETWEEN 3 AND 40, because it won't appear in my result set. Do you now understand? I want to have every COUNT(id) in my result set for values ranging from 3 to 40 even those where COUNT(id)=0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guess at what you are looking for:

```
select c.Value,  count(t.Value) as Count
from (
    select 3 as Value
    union all select 4
    union all select 5 
    union all select 6 
    union all select 7 
    union all select 8 
    union all select 9 --add more as needed
) c
left outer join MyTable t on c.Value = t.Value
group by c.Value
```

Comment: I don't know what it means at all. I want to check if value is equal to 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ..., 40, but not between 3 or 40, equal each number from 3 to 40.

Comment: @Vincent: see my update, just extrapolate from the code as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is something like:

```sql
SELECT value, count(id) FROM table
WHERE value BETWEEN 3 AND 40
GROUP BY value
```

But that won't give you any count(id) = 0 rows for values that don't exist.